# how data marts works in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, datamart

Normal data warehouses we create data marts for different teams. How does it differ in Snowflake?
In snowflake, we can create a database and share it with others. Can someone please explain data marts behavior in snowflake? Do we need to crate separate data marts like we normally do or any other approach use in snowflake?

Comment: How you structure your data in a data warehouse is generally independent of the DBMS you are using (assuming we are just talking about relational databases). Why do you think using Snowflake would have any impact on this? I'm guessing from your question that you have some pre-conceived ideas about Snowflake - so it would probably help if you updated your question to give some more detail about what you think Snowflake is/how it works and therefore why you are asking this question

Answer (score 0):

Both the approach has pros and cons, I prefer to keep one persisted Common Datamart and then virtual team/function/user specific Data marts. This is because sometime you not only want to filter out some data but also you may want to expose limited columns to user specific Data mart.